# MTM & RSA Authentication - Is anyone doing this?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, rsa

Is it possible to run MTM Test Controllers and Agents using RSA Authentication? I have not been able to find any info on the net related to RSA and MTM limitations. I suspect that RSA & MTM are not playing well together. If this is the problem does anyone know of a possible work around?

I am trying to set up a test controller/agent combination using 2012 MTM but I cannot get the Environment to Start. It appears that everything is configured correctly; however, when the VM with the controller/agent attempts to restart I encounter the error messages below and the Environment Status states that it is “Not Ready”.

Environment message: Type=Error; Message=TF259098: Team Foundation Server could not perform the following operation because of errors on one or more virtual machines: Update environment. Resolve those errors, and then try the operation again.;

Machine messages:
Machine name: SPF43Dev01
Machine message: Type=Error; Message=Microsoft Test Manager could not complete the following action: Validating the user name and password for coded UI tests.
Additional information: TF260948: The user name or password provided to configure the test agent to run as a process are not valid.

Error code: 1326;

---

Comment: Does this involve programming on your part?

Comment: No, we are trying to use the Lab Manger straight out of the box.

Comment: Ah, I see now, it does involve an IDE, wondered if it was on topic or not. Unfortunately I do not know the answer, all I can do is vote up. Note that you should take a good look at the tags you are using; use the ones with a high amount of followers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback.

I have solved th eissue. I turns out that  I needed to user the same domain user accouunt for all  logins for the server, controller and agent. I was loging into the sever as a domaine user, however I was trying to execute the agent in a local user account.